# Soundmanager 2: All buttons working except for 'Play' when streaming from Soundcloud

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud, soundmanager2

I have a site that's using Soundmanager 2 to steam music using Soundcloud.

Everything seems to be working fine, with the exception of the play button (in the footer). If the user presses 'Previous' or 'Next', sound will play with no issues and the 'Pause' / 'Play' buttons will function perfectly. It's essentially the play button not playing sound when freshly loaded.

You can view the site here: http://socialscar.plastiqueband.com

A link to the jQuery can be found here in /static/js/application.js

The player functions can be found on lines 1032 - 1044 of the homepage source code.

This code is based entirely from this working example: soundcloud-sm2.heroku.com, only changing the Client ID and Soundcloud URL where appropriate, so I'm totally out of ideas for why this isn't working.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be so grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, seems this is now fixed. Line 156 of application.js should have been

```
$('.tracks li:first').click();
```

instead of

```
$('li:first').click();
```

Knew is would be something very simple :)